# csla 4.5.600 -> csla 5.3.1 migration big issues

Tags: c#, migration, csla

We've been using CSLA 4.5.600 for years, for some reasons migration to every more newest version was postponed. 
Now, we'd like migrate to latest one (5.3.1)
mostly it was OK, we've got compilation errors (interfaces as incmoing parameters instead of objects etc) but we were ready for this. Eventually we fixed all compile-time errors. Ran test, most of them were OK.
But we are not ready to faced with problems with "child" objects.
Seems, there are some changes deeply inside of CSLA core, that produced hard to find bugs.
Seems, it goes for properties **IsNew**, **IsDirty**, **IsSavable** etc 
Example:
we have some class, let's name it **Parent** 
we've have some **Child** class that is a property on this **Parent** object.
we have tables **Table1** and **Table2**
we create an object **Parent1** it must be stored in the **Table1** and his **Child** Property will be stored in the **Table2** (parentid) must target parent1'id in the **Table1**
we create an object **Parent2** it must be stored in the **Table1** and his **Child** Property (parentid) must target parent2'id in the **Table1**. 
In the CSLA 4.5.600 we did something like that:

```
Csla.Data.DataMapper.Map(parent1, parent2, true);
Csla.Data.DataMapper.Map(parent1.Child, parent2.Child, true);
```

and **Child** property on **parent2** has:

```
IsNew = true
IsDirty = true
IsSavable = true
```

but if we're using CSLA 5.3.1 this code provides us:

```
IsNew = FALSE (!!!!)
IsDirty = true
IsSavable = true
```

so, instead of creating a new record in the **Table2** for parent's2 child, it updates a record for Child's property of the parent1's object!

so, workaround for CSLA 5.3.1 is:

```
string[] ignoreList = new string[] {"Child", "IsNew", "IsDirty" };
Csla.Data.DataMapper.Map(parent1, parent2, true, ignoreList );
Csla.Data.DataMapper.Map(parent1.Child, parent2.Child, true, ignoreList );
```

but, wel, we have hundreds of classes. Our project heavily based on CSLA. Of course, it was very big mistake not to update to every latest CSLA release, even we had some reason to stay on old version, but, well, now is October 2020 and we need somehow to understand **when** this breaking changes were introduced, **how** they are affecting not only **mapping** but something else also? 
 Problem not just to find workaround for this mapping, 
Idea is to understand how this changes somewhere inside of deep internals of CSLA affects all  CSLA functionality, which also is "broken" but we have no idea that is broken because of no compilation errors and we have about 60% tests coverage of existing codebase/functionality, but 40% still has no tests, so 
We bought all CSLA books already few years ago, but they are targeting CSLA 4, so, they couldn't help us with CSLA 5 breaking behavior. 
Reading github "release notes" didn't help much. Is there a blog post, or youtube videos or something else that could explain questions above?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is a bug in #cslanet - though the tests for CSLA itself haven't changed and continue to pass.

Can you provide a simple repro of the issue and file it as an issue in the repo?

https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/issues

(it sounds like the bug might be in DataMapper, which did get some updates, and so it is possible a bug was introduced there)

Comment: I haven't seen a post in the repo about this, is it still a problem for you?

It could be related to this known issue: https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/issues/902

Also, you might try using AutoMapper, which came along after DataMapper, and is more comprehensive in many ways.

Comment: I am very excuse  for my long silence. I started work on a separate test project to illustrate this problem in order not to inadvertently expose commercial code protected by the NDA. Then there was an illness,  I am going to return to work this Monday and also resume work on this test project. But, I just saw your message about AutoMapper, and the github issue, it turns out, this problem was already encountered in 2018 and since then it has not been fixed. Ok, I will rewrite all the code using Csla.Data.DataMapper to use an AutoMapper